# Challenges on my Windows Server DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I am a pretty much self-taught IT engineer with limited knowledge on DNS, so please pardon me if my question seems odd or just plain stupid....

I recently done a IPSec tunnel with our customer and they have like almost 30 hosts that has to be added into each individual computer host file to get the IP resolved(a.domain.com,b.domain.com all of which are not listed on public DNS)

As there is a large number of computers, and they have to add host name from time to time... it is a challenge for me as I am not stationed at this office.

What I have done now is to add those host name into my domain DNS with the forward lookup zone of my customer's domain name so that i do not have to change individual computer's host file.

Of course, with this implemented, i will not be able to get to my customer's website (www.domain.com) because it is not in my DNS server...

Is there a way for me to configure my DNS server to look for public DNS server when the host is not listed in my forward lookup zone?(example... xyz.domain.com is not listed in my DNS).

Comment: Have a look at `dnsmasq` software.

Comment: dnsmasq is only on Linux right?

Comment: It's odd or just plain stupid that the other end doesn't already have their own DNS.

Comment: Simmy, don’t create your own zone - that leads to the issue you describe and having to duplicate records. If the customer has their own domain then they clearly have their own DNS server(s). Simply create a conditional forwarder on your DNS server for their domain name. Send all requests for their domain name to their DNS server(s).